# Face A Common Enemy

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions, usage, collocations

I have question about the usage of "*in*".

According to definition 22 of this [dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/in_1) for "*in*" , "*in*" could be used like these sentences:

> 1. You ***have*** a very good friend ***in*** Pat.
> 2. ***In*** Dwight D. Eisenhower the Republicans had ***found*** the ideal candidate.

So, this sense of "*in*" should be,  according to the dictionary then, used with "*have*" or "*find*".  But then, I found this [news article](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/08/05/world/middleeast/iraq-agrees-to-help-kurds-battling-sunni-extremists.html):

> Still, Mr. Maliki’s support of the Kurds came after weeks in which the two militaries kept an uneasy distance from each other, even as Western officials, arguing that they ***faced a common enemy in ISIS***, urged cooperation.

The verb "*face*" is neither "*have*" or "*find*".  So, is the usage in news article wrong?

EDIT:  After some discussion with some forum members, it was pointed out that the following:

> 3. You ***have*** a very good friend ***in*** Pat.
> 4. The scene ***awoke*** a warrior ***in*** John.

use two different definitions of "*in*".  Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in that definition #22 that requires "have" or "find"--those are just examples. The quoted article is using the word the same way, and is quite correct.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand Definition 22 of the word **in** in *Longman's*.

The definition does not imply that *only* **have** and **find** can take the preposition **in** in this sense. It uses those two verbs only to demonstrate the way in which **in** relates to the verb. Other examples of such usage might be:

> **In** Tim Kaine, Hillary Clinton **named** a capable candidate for VP.
>   Julia Child **created** a classic **in** her *boeuf bourguignon*.

Comment: So, I could write something like:  "The scene ***awoke*** the warrior ***in*** him"?

Comment: @meatie It's not the same usage as in Definition 22, but that sentence is grammatically correct. "The scene awoke the warrior in him" is an example of the usage described in Definition 23 from Longman's.

Comment: Why do "*awoke the warrior* ***in*** *him*" and "*have a friend* ***in*** *him*" use different definitions of "*in*"?

Comment: @meatie It's not "have a friend in him." It's "Have a friend in **Pat**." Def. 22 has .."used before the **name of someone** or something when you are saying how they are regarded." Def. 23 has .. "used to say what person or thing has the quality you are mentioning." But it's a difficult call either way. The most important thing for you to understand is that there are **many** verbs that take **in** in this way.

Comment: I added a sub-question to my original post.   Would you kindly offer some comments to that ?  Thanks!

Comment: @meatie Looking again at _awoke the warrior in him_, the phrase *does* satisfy Definition 22 in _Longman's_. The pronoun "him" satisfies the phrase "name of someone" in that definition. The most important thing for you to understand is not which number from _Longman's_ is appropriate, but how these verbs take the preposition **in**.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if you switch the sentence around it would seem more understandable?

> In Pat, you have a very good friend.

Having written it this way, it's easier to illustrate the usage of `in`.

### How they are regarded, inside; internally.

So this usage is to express how someone is regarded, just as the definition 22 says.  It's a bit metaphorical, because you're not literally saying that there is something tangible inside Pat.

Consider these other examples

> Cameron has a talent in instruments.
>
> Peter has a job in education
>
> Alf has a vice in cats.
>
> John has problems in math

Notice that I didn't say math *class*.  I used math as a noun.  You can't literally put something inside math, but you can certainly have a belief in math.

Switch it around.

> In Math, John has problems.

Hope this helps.